# Copy and paste from excel to word in order

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word

I'm trying to copy 24 graphs from one excel worksheet to a word document in a particular order. This is the code I am using:

```
Sub ChartsToWord()

Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document
Dim iCht As Integer
Dim Msg As String

Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WDDoc = WDApp.Documents.Add


For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
' copy chart as a picture
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iCht).Chart.CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

WDApp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

WDDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
Next

WDDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Users\Brooklyn.Bodnarchuk\Desktop\Shell I&C Mini Pilot Results\Test 0 - Nov 23 2016\charts.doc")
WDDoc.Close ' close the document


Set WDDoc = Nothing
Set WDApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

My problem is that it seems to add the charts to the document in a completely random order. I have the charts named as "Chart 1", "Chart 2" and so on. How can I control the order in which these are copied and pasted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the charts named then you can use something like:

```
For iCht = 1 to ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart " & iCht).Chart.CopyPicture _
        Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ''etc

Next iCht
```

...assuming all chartobjects on the sheet are named "Chart x" in the order you want them to be copied.